# Receiving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento-1.9, php, swatches, server-setup, color-swatches

I did not even change any code or configure other than changing image in my slide show, which I have done earlier but I am continuously receiving these two errors on some of my pages including homepage and I have no idea why. Could anyone from the community please help me how to solve these errors? I am still learning Magento.

**Below is the error:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   /home/ommobhm2/public_html/narzary/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Data.php
>   on line 82
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   /home/ommobhm2/public_html/narzary/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php
>   on line 90

Comment: are you using shared hosting ? try contact hosting team once.

Comment: I talked to hosting provider but they said problem is not due to server but coding

Comment: okay, can you take backup of these files & copy fresh magento 1.9 files and check once.

Comment: How many products and attributes do you have? The configurable swatches module doesn't perform well under large datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue I'm pretty sure there's a post about it on Magento SE but can't get my hands on it.

Basically there's a speed bug in the `attachConfigurableProductChildrenAttributeMapping` method of `Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Mediafallback`

To fix the issue copy this file to `app/code/local/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php` and move the following snippet:

```
 $optionLabels = array_map(function ($value) {
  return array_map('Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::normalizeKey', $value);
 }, $optionLabels);
```

Before this code:

```
foreach($parentProducts as $parentProduct) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me solve my problem. You won't believe that I paid $20 to a guy in freelancer to solve this issue and he solved it just by disabling the Configurable Swatches. For hours I thought he really solved it, until I noticed that it was simply disabled. I had no time so had to pay for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @JwngdowNarzary sad to hear. Feel free to post your questions here and on the Magento forums, the community is great and you'll always find someone willing to help.

Comment: thank you @RaphaelatDigitalPianism you save my Day.. +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

Edit `php.ini` file. Find the line `max_execution_time` and change its value to 300:

```
max_execution_time = 300 //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

or write one of the below line of code in the `index.php` in the root

> `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

or

> `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //no limit`

Answer (score -1):

Magento use more resources sometime it is only the case when you have more than 2000 products, so use:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

in the `index.php` in the root.